# onDraw how to continue drawing over the previous graphics

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I am working on a Paint app. I want the drawings like each `line` or `oval` on their own layers, on top of each other. The `onDraw` method refreshes the whole `canvas` each time it is called and erase all the previous drawings. I want the previous drawings to be there and draw more over them. Here is my code of the onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint);
    if(drawOval){
        drawOval = false;
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, myPaint);
    }
}
```

It refreshes the canvas as soon as I start drawing something. I was restoring the previous state this way.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, myPaint);
```

**I want each drawing on its own layer above all the others previously drawn.**

Good ways to retire from this task. Thanks!

Comment: May be you are looking for canvas.save method https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/content/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-11-canvas/11-1-c-the-canvas-class/11-1-c-the-canvas-class.html

Comment: No, Definitely not. `canvas.save()` is for saving the current state (rotation and translation...) of the canvas and `canvas.restore()` restore the previously saved state. `canvas.save()` doesn't do anything with the drawings.